# I have a list inside of a list which need to be put into a dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list

```
[[[12, 71.2989367, -156.7286143, Samuel Simmonds Memorial Hospital, 4], [4, 64.8311569, -147.7399471, Fairbanks Memorial Hospital, 4].1, [6, 64.4993412, -165.3776787, Norton Sound Regional Hospital, 4].2, [5, 61.56316029999999, -149.2576383, Mat-Su Regional Medical Center, 4]]
```

Need this to be converted to something like on a dataframe:

```
ID  Lat           Long            Name                         Level

12, 71.2989367, -156.7286143, Samuel Simmonds Memorial Hospital, 4
4, 64.8311569, -147.7399471, Fairbanks Memorial Hospital, 4
6, 64.4993412, -165.3776787, Norton Sound Regional Hospital, 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward. Quote the strings, remove the extra level in the list.

```py
import pandas as pd

input_data = [[12, 71.2989367, -156.7286143, 'Samuel Simmonds Memorial Hospital', 4],
              [4, 64.8311569, -147.7399471, 'Fairbanks Memorial Hospital', 4],
              [6, 64.4993412, -165.3776787, 'Norton Sound Regional Hospital', 4],
              [5, 61.56316029999999, -149.2576383, 'Mat-Su Regional Medical Center', 4]]

df = pd.DataFrame(input_data,
                    columns=['ID', 'Lat', 'Long', 'Name', 'Level'])
```

Result:

```py
    ID  Lat     Long    Name    Level
0   12  71.298937   -156.728614     Samuel Simmonds Memorial Hospital   4
1   4   64.831157   -147.739947     Fairbanks Memorial Hospital     4
2   6   64.499341   -165.377679     Norton Sound Regional Hospital  4
3   5   61.563160   -149.257638     Mat-Su Regional Medical Center  4
```

Answer (score 0):

the regular `DataFrame` constructor should do it, just bear in mind that your data has some rouge `.`s is a 3-level nested list (so you need to access it with [0])

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [[
    [12, 71.2989367, -156.7286143, "Samuel Simmonds Memorial Hospital", 4],
    [4, 64.8311569, -147.7399471, "Fairbanks Memorial Hospital", 4],
    [6, 64.4993412, -165.3776787, "Norton Sound Regional Hospital", 4],
    [5, 61.56316029999999, -149.2576383, "Mat-Su Regional Medical Center", 4]
]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[0], columns=["ID","Lat","Long","Name","Level"])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   ID        Lat        Long                               Name  Level
0  12  71.298937 -156.728614  Samuel Simmonds Memorial Hospital      4
1   4  64.831157 -147.739947        Fairbanks Memorial Hospital      4
2   6  64.499341 -165.377679     Norton Sound Regional Hospital      4
3   5  61.563160 -149.257638     Mat-Su Regional Medical Center      4
```

Comment: The data file is actually in a .txt file and when I uses pandas dataframe to import it all of them become columns. Is there a way around this?